# Amazon AWS www CNAME is 403 forbidden, domain without www works

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, amazon-web-services, domain, subdomain

I have two domains that I bought through Google domains running on an EC2 instance from AWS. I added an A record to point to my elastic IP and I added a CNAME record for www that also points to the same elastic ip.

I am able to ping both websites with no issue, however, when I navigate to the domain with the www in front, I get 403 forbidden.  When I navigate to the domain without the www, I am able to see the website.

The security group has a record to allow all HTTP connections, RDP, and all ICMP connections.  What could be preventing the www website from working?  Perhaps a setting in IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes mostly, it is an issue with web server not listening or providing content for the www.example.com domain and just the example.com domain.

Comment: This could help : https://support.gearhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/200341725-Add-a-domain-alias-in-IIS-7

Comment: Yes! That was it. Looks like IIS also needs to be configured to accept www.  Thank you.